# How to use Laravels Auth method to authenticate access to a controller?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, routes

I've been reading http://codehappy.daylerees.com and getting into Laravel gradually, but I stumbled upon some confusion after trying to get authentication working.

The examples on that site in the majority use closures and basically do a lot of things I personally do in controllers inside the `routes.php` file. No problem, Laravel let's me use controllers and routes, however let's say I wish to restrict access to my admin panel in the routes. So don't let users go to `http://example.com/admin` without first authenticating. The explanations cover that, but using closures/anonymous functions. So with closures it would look like this:

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function() {
  // return admin view
}));
```

So I tried to use it the same way, but with a controller like this:

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => 'admin_controller@index'));
```

Which results in a white page.

So my question is how can I forward the 'get' to a controller instead of handling it with a closure while still authenticating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uses` instead of `do`

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'admin_controller@index'));
```